# Can't find Google Python API sync example

Tags: google-api, google-api-python-client, google-calendar-api, google-python-api

I need to see an example of Google Calendar API Sync (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync) working with Python. Can someone please provide me with one?

Answer (score 0):

You may check this [tutorial](https://code.google.com/archive/p/googlecalendarsync/). This tool is written in python to bidirectional synchronize a local iCal (.ics) file with Google Calendar.

**How to use googlecalendarsync**

> Create a configuration file (`$HOME/.googlecalsync/config`) using the following template:
>
> ```
> [google] username = password =[local] ical_file = workdir = ${HOME}/.googlecalsync/work/
> ```
>
> Then run: `googlecalsync.py [--dry-run]`

**Recommended usage**

> Add an entry in crontab (as non-privileged user) like the following to synchronize a local calendar with Google Calendar every 30mins:
>
> `0,30 * * * * /usr/bin/googlecalsync.py >/dev/null 2>&1`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example how to partial sync with python:

```
def get_list_event_update():
    calendar_id = "xxx@gmail.com"
    url_get_list_event_update = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/" + calendar_id + "/events"
    querystring = {"syncToken": "here_synctoken"}
    response = requests.request("GET", url_get_list_event_update, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    print(response.text)
```